# In JQuery, how do I add all the values of "checked" checkboxes together?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="checkbox" class="new_message" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="new_message" value="2"  checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" class="new_message" value="4" checked="checked">



total_score = $("input.new_message").checked.each(function(){
    ...? 
});
```

The total score should be 6.  I want to add all the checked values up of the same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start a counter, then increment it on each pass. `$.each` won't return anything.

```
var total_score = 0;
$("input.new_message:checked").each(function(){
    total_score += parseInt($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
var total_score = function () {
      var x = 0 ;
        $("input.new_message:checked").each(function(){
       x +=  Number($(this).val());
      });

    return x ; 

  }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N5xfK/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
var total_score = 0;

$('input.new_message:checked').each(function(){
    total_score += Number($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Gotta love the reactivity on this website :)

Answer (score -1):

```
 var sum = 0; 

$("input.new_message").each(function(){
    if($(this).prop(checked)){
    sum += $(this).val(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: he can not do `$(selector).checked.each()` this is not valid

Comment: Can you test your answers before posting